# Is it OK to hold back ack for a long time in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it OK for a consumer (in manual ack mode) to hold back the ack message for a long time?

The use case is that a process (the consumer) processes messages from a queue (ack is set to manual), the processing takes a long time (several minutes to hours), after the processing is done, an ack is sent back.

Is RabbitMQ server/client designed to handle this kind of usage pattern?

Comment: Anectodal, and not necessarily a good idea, but I've seen an ack being used as a distributed lock pattern, where competing consumers will compete to acquire an ack on a single (or finite amount) of messages on a queue. The idea was that if a consumer process crashed, that the message ack would be released for the next consumer to acquire. Consumers would typically hold an ack for a day or more, and Rabbit seemed to have no issue doing this.

Answer (score 2):

This design can be done, but is not strongly recommended.  Starting in RabbitMQ 3.8.15, there is a new feature that will close connections if a message is unacknowledged longer than the configuration.  So you will want to ensure that the configuration is set for a duration greater than what your clients will experience.  See [consumer_timeout documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#acknowledgement-timeout).